# Text in a class - href statement

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How could i get all the categories mentioned on each listing page of the same website "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category". for example, when i choose alcoholic beverage category on the above mentioned page, the listings mentioned on that page has the category information like this :-

```
Catergory: Alcoholic Beverage, Bottled Beverage, Spirit / Liquor / Hard Liquor, Wine, Distributor, Exporter, Importer, Supplier
```

how can i extract the categories mentioned here with in same variable.

The code i have written for this is :-

```
category = soup_2.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'clink'})
links = [links['href'] for links in category]
cat_name = [cat_name.text.strip() for cat_name in links]
```

but it is producing the below output which are all the links on the page & not the text with in the href:-

```
['http://www.sfma.org.sg/about/singapore-food-manufacturers-association',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/about/council-members',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/about/history-and-milestones',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/membership/',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/member/',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/member/alphabet/',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/sme-portal',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/setting-up-food-establishments-in-singapore',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/import-export-requirements-and-procedures',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/labelling-guidelines',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/wsq-continuing-education-modular-programmes',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/holistic-industry-productivity-scorecard',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/resources/p-max',
 'http://www.sfma.org.sg/event/',
  .....]
```

What i need is the below data for all the listings of all the categories on the base URL which is "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/"

```
['Ang Leong Huat Pte Ltd',
'16 Tagore Lane
 Singapore (787476)',
'Tel: +65 6749 9988',
'Fax: +65 6749 4321',
'Email: sales@alh.com.sg',
'Website: http://www.alh.com.sg/',
'Catergory: Alcoholic Beverage, Bottled Beverage, Spirit / Liquor / Hard Liquor, Wine, Distributor, Exporter, Importer, Supplier'
```

Please excuse if the question seems to be novice, i am just very new to python,

Thanks !!!

Comment: you've kind of snuck another question in there at the end. You open with how do I get all the category info and then at the very end say and x,y,z.

Comment: My question is still the same, how can i get the names of all the categories mentioned on each listing

Comment: unfortunately, none of the solution could get me the desired output

Comment: Apart from categories, i have managed to scrapped other data, but failing to get the names of the categories of each listing

Comment: I think my original (and current) answer gave you the categories against the company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following targets the two javascript objects housing mapping info about companies names, categories and the shown tags e.g. bakery product. More more detailed info on the use of regex and splitting item['category'] - see my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57214952/6241235).

It handles unquoted keys with hjson library.

You end up with a dict whose keys are the company names (I use `permalink` version of name, over `name`,  as this should definitely be unique), and whose values are a tuple with 2 items. The first item is the company page link; the second is a list of the given tags e.g. bakery product, alcoholic beverage). The logic is there for you to re-organise as desired.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import hjson

base = 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/info/'
p = re.compile(r'var tmObject = (.*?);')
p1 = re.compile(r'var ddObject = (.*?);')
r = requests.get('https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/manufacturer')
data = hjson.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
lookup_data = hjson.loads(p1.findall(r.text)[0])
name_dict = {item['id']:item['name'] for item in lookup_data['category']}
companies = {}

for item in data['tmember']:
    companies[item['permalink']] = (base + item['permalink'], [name_dict[i] for i in item['category'].split(',')])

print(companies)
```

---

Updating for your additional request at end (Address info etc):

I then loop `companies` dict visiting each company url in tuple item 1 of value for current dict key; extract the required info into a dict, which I add the category info to, then update the current key:value with the dictionary just created.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import hjson

base = 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/info/'
p = re.compile(r'var tmObject = (.*?);')
p1 = re.compile(r'var ddObject = (.*?);')
r = requests.get('https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/manufacturer')
data = hjson.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
lookup_data = hjson.loads(p1.findall(r.text)[0])
name_dict = {item['id']:item['name'] for item in lookup_data['category']}
companies = {}

for item in data['tmember']:
    companies[item['permalink']] = (base + item['permalink'], [name_dict[i] for i in item['category'].split(',')])

with requests.Session() as s:
    for k,v in companies.items():
        r = s.get(v[0])
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        tel = soup.select_one('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:contains(Tel)')    
        fax = soup.select_one('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:contains(Fax)')
        email = soup.select_one('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:contains(Email)')
        website = soup.select_one('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:contains(Website)')
        if tel is None:
            tel = 'N/A'
        else:
            tel = tel.text.replace('Tel: ','')
        if fax is None:
            fax = 'N/A'
        else:
            fax = fax.text.replace('Fax: ','') 
        if email is None:
            email = 'N/A'
        else:
            email = email.text.replace('Email: ','')
        if website is None:
            website = 'N/A'
        else:
            website = website.text.replace('Website: ','')
        info = {
                # 'Address' : ' '.join([i.text for i in soup.select('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:not(p:nth-child(n+4) ~ p)')])
                'Address' : ' '.join([i.text for i in soup.select('.w3-text-sfma ~ p:nth-child(-n+4)')])
                , 'Tel' : tel
                , 'Fax': fax
                , 'Email': email
                ,'Website' : website
                , 'Categories': v[1]
        }    
        companies[k] = info
```

---

**Example entry in `companies` dict:**

[image]

Comment: After providing a solution I could notice that you have already gone through that route, so I've deleted mine @QHarr.

Comment: @SIM I wouldn't necessarily. The OP has actually snuck multiple questions in instead of one (which I didn't even notice til I just saw your answer). I answered the first and you answered the second. I think OP should actually ask separate questions personally. Or have led up front with I want x,y,z. If you are happy to add in the category mapping bit (you can use mine as template if you want) - I will delete my answer.

Comment: The interesting thing is I wasn't aware of this library `hjson` until I came across one of your solutions. Btw, do you know whether microsoft has planned to add any json parser in vba? Thanks.

Comment: I learnt about hjson from another answer on here. And no, I don't know of any plans I'm afraid. I don't know of any VBA developments going on.

Comment: @sim I think it is a shame you deleted your answer tbh.

Comment: It makes me feel bad when I hear any such bad news about my fav language.

Comment: @IQHarr :- i am getting this error

  NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: 
  nth-of-type.

Comment: You need to upgrade your bs4 version to make the above script work for you. First try this `pip install bs4 --upgrade` and then run the script @renu.

Comment: Then your upgrade isn't being picked up perhaps. You want bs4 4.7.1 and soupsieve 1.8

Comment: i didn't mean to disregard the help, i posted it so that anyone else can also refer to 
it, apologies for that, i have deleted it now.

Comment: And i had already accepted the answer yesterday itself,
Thanks for all the help !!!

Comment: I have no idea whre this trail has come from as have been busy elsewhere but thanks :-)